# Pandas text matching like SQL's LIKE?

Tags: pandas, string-matching, sql-like

Is there a way to do something similar to [SQL's LIKE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) on a pandas text DataFrame column, such that it returns a list of indices, or a list of booleans that can be used for indexing the dataframe? For example, I would like to be able to match all rows where the column starts with 'prefix_', similar to `WHERE <col> LIKE prefix_%` in SQL.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the Series method [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) (which takes a regex):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['aa', 'ab', 'ca', np.nan])

In [12]: s.str.startswith('a', na=False)
Out[12]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

You can also do the same with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) (using a regex):

```
In [13]: s.str.contains('^a', na=False)
Out[13]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

*So you can do `df[col].str.startswith`...*

[See also the SQL comparison section of the docs.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html)

Note: (as pointed out by OP) by default NaNs will propagate (and hence cause an indexing error if you want to use the result as a boolean mask), we use this flag to say that NaN should map to False.

```
In [14]: s.str.startswith('a')  # can't use as boolean mask
Out[14]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3      NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for that Andy. My also be worth noting that for use when indexing, nans cause an error, because they return nan by default. You can use `s.str.startswith('a', na=False)` to force them to return False.

Comment: @naught101 good catch, actually I didn't know about that! That's neat.

Answer (score 17):

1. To find all the values from the series that starts with a pattern "s":

SQL - `WHERE column_name LIKE 's%'` 
Python - `column_name.str.startswith('s')`

2. To find all the values from the series that ends with a pattern "s":

SQL - `WHERE column_name LIKE '%s'`
Python - `column_name.str.endswith('s')`

3. To find all the values from the series that contains pattern "s":

SQL - `WHERE column_name LIKE '%s%'`
Python - `column_name.str.contains('s')`

For more options, check : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html

Answer (score 10):

you can use

```
s.str.contains('a', case = False)
```