# Conditional dataframe query in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

Given a dataframe with 3 columns

```
C1    C2      C3 
1.0   B1678   G
4.5   B1678   K
1.2   B1678   K
1.8   K1567   K
6.9   K1567   G
5.0   G1789   G
4.9   G1789   K
9.0   K1567   G
4.0   B1678   G
```

What would be the following sql equivalent statement in Python.

```
select sum(C1) 
where C2 like 'B%'
and C3 like '%K%';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas text matching like SQL's LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291565/pandas-text-matching-like-sqls-like)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you'd do it:

```
select = df[df["C2"].str.startswith("B") & (df["C3"] == "K")]
summation = select["C1"].sum()
```