# pandas dataframe - select rows that are similar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to select rows that are 'similar', (NOT DUPLICATES!) in a pandas dataframe?

I have a `dataframe` that has columns including `'school_name'` and `'district'`.

I want to see if there are any schools that have **similar** names in *different* districts.

All I can think of is to select a random school name and manually check if similar names exist in the `dataframe`, by running something like:

```
df[df['school_name'].str.contains('english grammar')]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

edit: I am ultimately going to **string match** this particular dataframe with another dataframe, on `school_name` column, while blocking on `district` column. The issue is that some district names in the two dataframes don't exactly match, due to district names changing over time -  df1 is from year 2000 and it has districts in 'city-i', 'city-ii'... format, whereas df2, which is from year 2020, has districts in 'city-south', 'city-north' ... format. The names have changed over time, and the districts have been reshuffled to get merged / separated etc.

So I am trying to remove the 'i', 'ii', 'south' etc to just block on 'city'. Before I do that I want to make sure that there are no similar-sounding names in 'city-i' and 'city-south', (because I wouldn't want to  match the similar sounding names together if the schools are actually in a completely different district).

Comment: How do you define similar?

Comment: have edited my post to include more detailed explanation - thank you!

Comment: You can try an approach called ["similar items"](https://www.todaysoftmag.com/article/1553/finding-similar-entities-in-bigdata-models) with an algorithm like this one: [Locality-Sensitive Hashing](https://github.com/kochlisGit/Algorithms-for-Big-Data/tree/master/lsh) the benefit is here that you can find indeed similar strings, not just some that contain the same substring

Comment: @dmswjd did you check my comment? I think this is what you're looking for

Comment: Yes - @Berger thank you so much!

Comment: If you cast the problem as a (dictionary-like) key-based lookup and your data is small enough, then you can consider string-matching techniques. For data input errors (typos/spelling errors/etc) I use `difflib` and a threshold (an explanation here: https://petescully.co.uk/2021/02/11/extension-of-python-dict-get-lookup-with-similarity-for-library-built-ins/)

Comment: Also see SQL `%LIKE%` matching in Pandas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291565/pandas-text-matching-like-sqls-like

Answer (score 0):

You can make two sets one will contain the school name and other will contain duplicates if it encounters duplicate while traversing each school name in the column

```
school=set()
duplicate=set()
for i in df1.schl_name:
    if i not in school:
        school.add(i)
    else:
        duplicate.add(i)

df1[df1['schl_name'].isin(duplicate)]
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering with code-only. Note that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of the question. Thus, please edit the post to contain an explanation as to why this line of code works.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I have edited. I hope the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Let`s say this is your DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'school':['High School',
                             'High School',
                             'Middle School',
                             'Middle School'], 
                   'district':['Main District',
                               'Unknown District',
                               'Unknown District',
                               'Some other District']
})
```

[image]

Than you can use a combination of `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated()` and `pandas.groupby()`.

```
df[df.duplicated('school', keep=False)].groupby('school')
                                       .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x['district']))
                                       .to_frame('duplicated names by district')
```

This returns a DataFrame which looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get all duplicated rows only, based on a column **school_name**:

```
df[df['school_name'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

If you want to get rows for a single **school_name** value:

```
# If we are searching for school let's say 'S1'
name = "S1"
df.loc[df['school_name'] == name]
```

To select rows, which have same **school_name** based on a given list, use `isin`

```
dupl_list = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3']
df.loc[df['school_name'].isin(dupl_list)]
```