# Add same row values to dataframe for all column with name LIKE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['aab', 'aac', 'bba'])
```

and I would like to add the same value to all columns which start with "aa%" something like this:

```
df = df.append({'aa%': 'val1', 'bba': 'val2'}, ignore_index=True)
```

and get this result:

```
+------+------+------+
| aab  | aac  | bba  |
+------+------+------+
| val1 | val1 | val2 |
+------+------+------+
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Look at [Pandas text matching like SQL's LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291565/pandas-text-matching-like-sqls-like)

Comment: A little but, this is a SELECT like, I want an INSERT like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use append to create empty row, then fill empty row with `val1` where column names starts with `aa`. Finally fill rest of values with `val2` :

```
df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)
df.loc[0, df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('aa')]] = 'val1'
df.fillna('val2')
```

result:

```
    aab   aac   bba
0  val1  val1  val2
```